# Windows 10 compatibility

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am considering an upgrade of my Windows 8.1 machine to Windows 10, but want to ensure that nightwatchjs is compatible with Windows 10. Has anybody successfully tried this combination?

Answer (score 2):

Reference with information in NightWatch JS Website.

NightWatch version 0.9.16 is support Windows 10 
(Please see http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/ then scroll down to Microsoft WebDriver section).

You will also find that Microsoft WebDriver support latest build of Windows 10 (Release 15063) and still support pervious build of Windows 10 too (Release 14393, Release 10586 and Release 10240). (Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ )

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question directly, but you can [roll back windows 10](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/windows-10-how-to-roll-back/) if you have issues. Alternatively, install Windows 10 in demo mode in a virtual machine.